# How to fix crash on 12.2 with cordova wkwebview

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, ios12

Our ionic App runs on fine on IOS version < 12.2 but now it crashes directly when started on IOS 12.2  with the following crash log:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _alwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority.'

Comment: I believe 12.2 is not yet released, only in beta sooooooooooooooooo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474910/ionic-app-crashes-on-ios-12-2-because-of-alwaysrunsatforegroundpriority