# ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public selectors _setAlwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority:

Tags: testflight

I just do the text change, before text it is working fine. Please anyone can help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve app validation "The app references non-public selectors in Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp: \_setAlwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority:"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373661/how-to-resolve-app-validation-the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payloa)

Answer (score 4):

I've solved with:

- ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@4.1.0
- ionic cordova build ios

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue I resolved:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@4.1.0
Delete platform/ios
ionic cordova build ios
```