# Invalid Binary error after submit updated version

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

i'm trying to update my application on app store, but i'm getting this error "Invalid Binary",

and this email:

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent submission for App Store review for your app, "app name" 0.0.3 (0.0.3). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public selectors in AppName: _setAlwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority:. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. If you think this message was sent in error and that you have only used Apple-published APIs in accordance with the guidelines, send the app's Apple ID, along with detailed information about why you believe the above APIs were incorrectly flagged, to appreview@apple.com. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Best regards,

The App Store Team

i don't know what is wrong

Comment: The error message is very precise. What part are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Also: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373661/how-to-resolve-app-validation-the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payloa

Comment: i don understand what this email mean

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, the message explains well what is the problem, in the app is used internal API which is forbidden. You need to check where exactly this can be used, is it in your code or some plugin that you used.

For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373661/how-to-resolve-app-validation-the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payloa) the problem comes from cordova-plugin-ionic-webview