# Apple Rejection - ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - databasePool:didAddDatabase:, databasePool:shouldAddDatabaseToPool:, ddSetLogLevel

Tags: ios, ionic4

Sick of this app store rejection. Anyway, I was trying submit my newly updated ionic4 app to appstore. but getting the following message from email after a successful upload from xcode.

ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public selectors in xxxx app: _setAlwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority:, databasePool:didAddDatabase:, databasePool:shouldAddDatabaseToPool:, ddSetLogLevel:. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. If you think this message was sent in error and that you have only used Apple-published APIs in accordance with the guidelines, send the app's Apple ID, along with detailed information about why you believe the above APIs were incorrectly flagged, to appreview@apple.com. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

If anyone knows how to resolve this issue. Please share. I've been spending weeks on fixing all kinds of ios related issues to get to this point and couldn't figure out how to fix this issue. thanks in advance

I tried the following solutions but none of them seem working

[How to resolve app validation "The app references non-public selectors in Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp: _setAlwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority:"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373661/how-to-resolve-app-validation-the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payloa)
  https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/issues/850
  https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/389

Comment: Hi! Do you found a solution? Have the same selectors: databasePool:didAddDatabase:, databasePool:shouldAddDatabaseToPool:, ddSetLogLevel:

Comment: Any solution???